# Quarto Hybrid Navigation Sidebar Always Shown

Tags: quarto

I adapted the YAML file for hybrid navigation as outlined in the Quarto documentation: [Hybrid Navigation](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/website-navigation.html#hybrid-navigation)
. Unfortunately, the Tutorial sidebar always appears, not just when I click on the Tutorial link in the navbar, which is not my intended behavior. Regrettably, the Quarto documentation I referred to doesn't explain how the platform determines when to display a sidebar. I assume it checks whether a file is listed in the sidebar. However, if that were the case, the sidebar shouldn't appear when I click on "About," but it does.

```
    project:
      type: website
      resources: tutorial.pdf, tutorial.R

    website:
      title: "test.org"

      navbar:
        background: secondary
        search: true
        left:
          - text: "About"
            file: index.qmd
          - text: "Tutorial"
          
      sidebar:
        - title: "Tutorial"
          style: "docked"
          background: light
          contents:
            - tutorial/before.qmd
            - tutorial/loading_data.qmd
            

    format:
      html:
        theme: cosmo
        css: styles.css
        toc: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this note in the [Website Navigation](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/website-navigation.html#hybrid-navigation) documentation that you provided, it is under the "Hybrid Navigation" section:

[image].

So, in your index.qmd, at the top it has to be

```
---
title: "About"
sidebar: false
```

Comment: Thanks the solved my problem! It's not entirely correct. You need to put the sidebar:false in the header index.qmd. I modified your answer accordingly.

Comment: @JulianKarch Cool! I just accepted that edit you suggested so we should have the right answer - if you think it looks correct you may want to accept the answer so future users know it works.